# Accessing one "item" of a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I wanted to access one "item" of my `map<wstring,wstring>`.

But this does not work:

```
for (unsigned int i=0;i<m_ValidCharacterTranslations.Content().size();i++)
{
    wstring wsFirst = &m_ValidCharacterTranslations.Content()[i]->first;
    wstring wsSecond = &m_ValidCharacterTranslations.Content().at(i)->second;
    //do something with these 2 wstrings
}
```

The error I am getting in the last line is:

```
No binary operator accepts the right-handed operand of type 'unsigned int'.
```

My class is declared like this:

```
clsTranslations m_ValidCharacterTranslations;

class clsTranslations : public CBaseStructure
{
private:
    map<wstring,wstring> m_content;
protected:
    virtual void ProcessTxtLine(string line);
public:
    map<wstring,wstring> &Content();
    void LoadTranslations(string file);
};
```

Can somebody tell me how to get these values?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Because what you're doing makes no sense on multiple levels. `Content` returns a `map` with key type `wstring`, you try to access a key of type `unsigned int` and try to assign the resulting **value** to a `map`.

Comment: Please try a simpler piece of code using `std::map` until you're comfortable with its interface.

Comment: You're still trying to access an `unsigned int` key in a map with key type `wstring`. Also, `map::at` doesn't return the kv-pair but only the value.

Comment: I would like to iterate through the map and use the first and the second wstring of the map.

Comment: [See the documentation of `std::map<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). It is pretty clear how they work. The same cannot be said about what you're doing, and the very first sentance in the very first comment, ("What are you trying to do?") remains to be answered.

Comment: I have changed the description once again.

Comment: What does the function `map<wstring,wstring> &Content();` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to iterate through the map and use the first and the
>   second wstring of the map.

C++11:

```
for (auto& kvpair : somemap) {
    cout << kvpair.first << " has value " << kvpair.second << std::endl;
}
```

pre C++11:

```
for (map<wstring,wstring>::iterator it = somemap.begin(); it != somemap.end(); it++) {
    cout << it->first << " has value " << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me, telling me "The type auto cannot be initiated".

Comment: Do you have a c++11 compiler? If not, try the second one.

Comment: I'm not an expert on VS, but maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293615(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You access first and second addresses, instead of values.

Comment: Put this as a comment please

Comment: @P0W a new user can't comment on other's questions.